# чем отличается символ \xa0 от простого пробела

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, символы

Ну вот допустим есть у нас такие примеры(на python)

1:

`print(repr(" "))`(если копировать этот пример через превью вопроса, то вместо \xa0 будет пробел, а если через редактор(править), то не заменяется)

2:

`print(repr(" "))`

По сути ничем не отличаются, но в первом символ \xa0, а во втором пробел.

Так вот, что это за символ? Зачем он нужен?

Comment: Неразрывный пробел, назначение — запрет переноса строки по словам в месте, где он стоит

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это разные символы:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name("\xa0")
'NO-BREAK SPACE'
>>> unicodedata.name("\x20")
'SPACE'
```

Назначение NO-BREAK SPACE ([неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB)) в том, чтобы автоматический перенос строки не появлялся на его месте.

Непечатаемые символы экранируются в repr, поэтому NO-BREAK SPACE превращается в \xa0, а обычный SPACE как есть остаётся:

```
>>> "\x20".isprintable()  # SPACE
True
>>> "\xa0".isprintable()
False
```

Comment: автоматический перенос строки это как ? Строка не переноситься пока не вставишь символ /n

Comment: @Gleb когда алгоритм на строки разбивает. В противоположность когда человек в ручную текст на строки разбивает.

Answer (score 2):

`\xa0` - это [неразрывный пробел](http://www.codetable.net/hex/a0).

Отличие описаны в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB):

> Элемент компьютерной кодировки текстов, отображающийся внутри строки
>   подобно обычному пробелу, но не позволяющий программам отображения и
>   печати разорвать в этом месте строку. Используется для автоматизации
>   вёрстки, правила которой предписывают избегать разрыва строк в
>   известных случаях (большей частью для удобочитаемости).