# не могу привести к int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

фрейм и значения `2 098, 2 0456, 1 234` и тд
не могу привести к `int`
смотрю .values

```
2\xa0098, 2\xa00456, 1\xa0234
```

Answer (score 1):

`\xa0` - это *неразрывный пробел*. Его только вручную заменять:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['2\xa0098', '2\xa00456', '1\xa0234']})
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace('\xa0', '').astype(int)
df
```

Вывод:

| index | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2098 |
| 1 | 20456 |
| 2 | 1234 |

Вот [ещё информация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/756138/260769).

Comment: Немного дополню. Неразрывный пробел — это специальный символ, который выглядит как пробел, но при переносе строки ведёт себя как цифробуквенный символ. Используется большинством текстовых процессоров (в том числе) для разбиения длинный чисел на группы цифр.